# Facebook "Like" and "Send" buttons disappeared

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Just a few days ago the Facebook Like and Send buttons disappeared from my site products pages. The code is still in place and has work for months before they disappeared. A link to one of the product pages is http://www.finesgas.com/details/gas_grill_brands/broilmaster_brands/popular_models/p3sx

The is the code that I have in place right now.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<meta property="og:title" content=" Broilmaster P3SX Grill With Portable Cart" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Broilmaster P3SX gas Grill With Portable Cart Base " />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="FinesGas" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1222761017" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.finesgas.com/images/broilmaster-p3sx-loaded.jpg" />

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like send="true" layout="button_count" width="250" show_faces="false" action="Like" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
<div style="padding:5px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your html tag...

```
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
```

Comment: I added the xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" to the html tag and the buttons still are not showing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: yes, use the html5 version of the like button: `<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="250" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

Comment: also, please regenerate all of your code here because it doesn't look quite right: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I will do that and let you know what happens. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I replaced the like button code from this

    <fb:like send="true" layout="button_count" width="250" show_faces="false" action=”Like” font=”Tahoma”></fb:like> 

to this 

    <fb:like send="true" layout="button_count" width="250" show_faces="false"></fb:like> 
 
I also added my app id to the script and all is good now. Thanks again for your time and advice.